# Sharing files between android apps?

Tags: android, file, sharing

Can anyone suggest how can we share a file between n number of android applications? Suggest me any links, code etc? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Use content providers for sharing data like SQLite database between your n number of android applications.

Comment: Use the `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("")` call to get the public directory path.

Answer (score 6):

Look at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider. This component can share a file from one app to any other apps in the system by means of a *content URI*, which allows the hosting app to use URI (not just file) permissions to control the file. This means that the hosting app can set *temporary* access permissions instead of permanently changing the file's permissions. There's no performance penalty, so every time an app needs a file it can get the content URI and temporary permissions. Very secure.

FileProvider is a subclass of ContentProvider, and works in roughly the same way.

The current reference doc is a bit vague. I'll try to summarize:

Hosting app needs to declare the provider in the manifest:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities=authority
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data>
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/some_name" />
</provider>
```

- "authority" is a URI authority you make up.
- some_name is the name of an XML file you put in your project (usually in the `xml/` subdirectory.

The contents of `some_name.xml` is

```
<paths>
    <files-path name="path-segment" path="filepath"/>
    ...
</paths
```

> files-path

shares files in your private file area (value returned by Context.getFilesDir()), but you can also share files in your external area and cache area.

```
filepath
```

is a subdirectory in your private file area, for example `images/`. `path-segment` is the corresponding path that goes into the content URI. For example, if you use an authority of

```
com.example.myapp.fileprovider
```

and put in

```
<files-path name="images" path="images/">
```

then the resulting content URI starts with

```
content://com.example.myapp.fileprovider/images
```

If you want to share out the file images/myimage.jpg, the resulting content URI is

```
content://com.example.myapp.fileprovider/images/myimage.jpg
```

The hosting app generates a content URI by calling `FileProvider.getUriForFile()

What's nice is that you don't have to implement a subclass of FileProvider in code; it's default behavior is sufficient for most people's needs.

See the javadoc for more info.

Answer (score 0):

All the applications would have to know the filename. Save the file to the SD card or internal memory and make sure it's public. Have a look at the Android developer site on this topic: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

I hope this helps.